# Which are the databases used in gtk?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

We can use databases sqlite,mysql etc with python and qt.But i dont know which database is used in gtk and how to use it.can anybody help me to find the database for gtk and also give some example for HOW TO USE IT (i am beginner).

Comment: There is no "the database" for gtk. Your database selection depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

GTK+, or the GIMP Toolkit, is a multi-platform toolkit for creating graphical user interfaces. Offering a complete set of widgets, but it is not a programming language itself. It is written in C but has been designed from the ground up to support a wide range of languages, not only C/C++. Using GTK+ from languages such as Perl and Python (especially in combination with the Glade GUI builder) provides an effective method of rapid application development, therefor you can use any of the technologies you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

As ergosys said, GTK favors no database API. You can use what you want.